# Regex for validating email length before '@'

Tags: php, regex

An open-source cms I'm working on uses the following regex for validating emails:

```
 valid_regex=^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)(.[a-z]{2,3})$
```

and I need to validate also the length of the email address before the '@' symbol to accept emails with at least 2 characters.. I've read that using {2,} will do the trick but where and how exactly should I use it?......

Comment: Read: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx

Comment: Why? There are email addresses with only one character there. There are also email addresses which include a `+` character (which would be rejected by your expression) and email addresses with TLDs that have more than three characters in it (also rejected).

Comment: It's not up to me my friend, the requirement is to accept 2 and above chars.

Comment: I need to change from 3 to 2 but I'm not sure how to.
I changed the regex above to valid_regex=^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+){2,}@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)(.[a-z]{2,3})$ but it didnt work.
If you don't have an answer then simply don't bother to flame my question. Sorry if I stepped on your toes.

Comment: That would have been a relevant information 42 minutes ago. I'm sorry if you had to wait for an answer: one dot too much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex will already force the email to be atleast 2 (or rather 3) characters before the @.

```
[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)
          ^            ^
```

In both cases you're using the `+` sign which symbols that the following character should be repeated 1 or many times. Note that this regex will not match several valid email-addresses and have a lot of other problems.

For a starter you should escape each dot using backslash `\.` and as it is now you force all addresses to have exactly one dot.

An easy solution would be to make the dot optional in your current regex:

```
[_a-z0-9-]+(\.?[_a-z0-9-]+)+
```

And I guess that you don't really want to limit the address to have only 1 dot in it. If you Do want that simply remove the last plus sign.

You can see it in action here: http://regexr.com?2vbof

Answer (score 2):

to validate an email, don't use regex. instead use

```
if (filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) {
```

If you still want to validate length before @, a simple

```
if (strpos($input, '@') < 2) {
```

should suffice.

Comment: You're aware that FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL is a regex?

Comment: @mario actually FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL equates to 274 on my version of PHP.

Comment: [Nevertheless it is](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L499). Also I'm just saying because it's just a bit too bemusing to see questions in the [regex] tag answered with "don't use regex" and then inadvertently recommend a regex.

Comment: @mario I see your point. I should have stated, "don't re-invent the wheel", instead.

Comment: The `=== true` might best be left out, as on success the email string will be returned. An `== true` or just leaving it to `if()` would work.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this incredibly complicated and thoroughly tested RegEx to validate the email address:

http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php